# bson_ext gem install fails on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, bson, bson-ext

I'm stuck with install bson_ext gem with 1.5.1 version. I've tried almost everything what I found on web but nothing helps.
I tried to reinstall ruby, rvm and so on.

I am using:

- RVM
- MacOs Catalina 10.15.6
- ruby 2.6.5

and after bundle install I got log like this:

```
Fetching bson_ext 1.5.1
Installing bson_ext 1.5.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1/ext/cbson
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20201001-15946-1sze5ll.rb extconf.rb
checking for asprintf()... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for ruby/regex.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1/ext/cbson
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1/ext/cbson
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bson_buffer.c
compiling cbson.c
cbson.c:118:36: warning: passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'const unsigned char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    result_t status = check_string(RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string),
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:5: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_PTR'
    (!(RBASIC(str)->flags & RSTRING_NOEMBED) ? \
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./encoding_helpers.h:26:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'string' here
result_t check_string(const unsigned char* string, const int length,
                                           ^
cbson.c:118:57: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    result_t status = check_string(RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string),
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cbson.c:118:57: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    result_t status = check_string(RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string),
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
cbson.c:128:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    SAFE_WRITE(buffer, RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string));
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1000:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:996:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^
cbson.c:68:46: note: expanded from macro 'SAFE_WRITE'
    if (bson_buffer_write((buffer), (data), (size)) != 0)                    \
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~
cbson.c:128:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    SAFE_WRITE(buffer, RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string));
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/lukasz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1001:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
                           ^
cbson.c:68:46: note: expanded from macro 'SAFE_WRITE'
    if (bson_buffer_write((buffer), (data), (size)) != 0)                    \
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~
cbson.c:303:20: warning: unused variable 'values' [-Wunused-variable]
            VALUE* values;
                   ^
cbson.c:602:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'bson_buffer_get_max_size' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (length > bson_buffer_get_max_size(buffer)) {
                 ^
cbson.c:602:18: note: did you mean 'bson_buffer_set_max_size'?
./bson_buffer.h:34:6: note: 'bson_buffer_set_max_size' declared here
void bson_buffer_set_max_size(bson_buffer_t buffer, int max_size);
     ^
6 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [cbson.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/bson_ext-1.5.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bson_ext (1.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  bson_ext
```

Anyone has idea what can I try else?
In addition I can say that bson_ext with other version like 1.9.1 are installing successfully. But in this project I have to use 1.5.1.

Comment: Did you try to run a separate gem install command as suggested in the output below?
`gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`. Sometimes it may give you some additional context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked for me on MacOS 11.2.

`gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 33):

I found a better solution, when you install the gem add this at the end

```
-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: here is the full command:  `gem install bson_ext -v '1.5.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 2):

1.5.1 is 9 years old, so there's no reason to believe that it should work. And, indeed, it also fails for me with the same error (Big Sur / 2.7.1 and 2.8.0).

That being said, if you 100% insist on doing this, and have no alternatives such as changing employers and/or a promising career in software archaeology to fall back on, try this:

Go to the folder indicated in the error message, `/Users/lukasz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bson_ext-1.5.1 for inspection.`

From there, go to `ext/cbson` and edit the file `bson_buffer.h`.

You need to insert one line, near to the top of the file:

```
/* A buffer */
typedef struct bson_buffer* bson_buffer_t;
/* A position in the buffer */
typedef int bson_buffer_position;

/***** THE FOLLOWING IS THE LINE YOU NEED TO INSERT ****/
int bson_buffer_get_max_size(bson_buffer_t buffer); 

 /* Allocate and return a new buffer.
 * Return NULL on allocation failure. */
bson_buffer_t bson_buffer_new(void);
```

run `make` in that folder. It should work with just a few warnings.

After that, you still need to install it. Check `gem help install` for details on the process. This is following its instructions:

```
@ in bson_ext-1.5.1 $ gem spec ../../cache/bson_ext-1.5.1.gem --ruby > ../../specifications/bson_ext-1.5.1.gemspec
```

And, indeed:

```
@ in bson_ext-1.5.1 $ gem list bson_ext
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bson_ext (1.5.1)
```

Note that this was in the "original" folder again.

Even after that, just doing requite 'bson_ext' does not work for me and require 'bson' complains about it missing. According to that error message, you might succeed by moving–and I want to be very specific here–*something*, *somewhere*.
No guarantee this will actually work. Probably not.

Comment: Nice fix, I didn't had the gemspec file in my specifications folder. I added ad empty file with the name `bson_ext-1.5.1.gemspec`

then ran the command:

`$ gem spec ../../cache/bson_ext-1.5.1.gem --ruby > ../../specifications/bson_ext-1.5.1.gemspec`

Answer (score 1):

Installing 1.3.1 version worked for me

Comment: I understand but I can't change version in this project and I am obligated to use 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need exactly that version of that gem or it's just default required in your project?
If not you can just explicitly set latest/installed version of gem in Gemfile like:

```sh
gem list bson_ext                                                                         

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bson_ext (1.12.5)
```

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.12.5'
```

This worked form me under MacOS BigSur when by default bundle install was trying to install bson_ext -v '1.5.1', and exited with error like your:

```sh
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
                           ^
cbson.c:68:46: note: expanded from macro 'SAFE_WRITE'
    if (bson_buffer_write((buffer), (data), (size)) != 0)                    \
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~
cbson.c:303:20: warning: unused variable 'values' [-Wunused-variable]
            VALUE* values;
                   ^
cbson.c:602:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'bson_buffer_get_max_size' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (length > bson_buffer_get_max_size(buffer)) {
                 ^
cbson.c:602:18: note: did you mean 'bson_buffer_set_max_size'?
./bson_buffer.h:34:6: note: 'bson_buffer_set_max_size' declared here
void bson_buffer_set_max_size(bson_buffer_t buffer, int max_size);
     ^
6 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [cbson.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```